# Why is my date object returning back NaN values?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, countdowntimer, clearinterval

My program is supposed to start a countdown timer that calculates the time remaining in days, hours, seconds, etc from today till the the date that the user picks in the input field.

**While the program updates the HTML with the correct time remaining, the problem starts when I try to update countdown timer every second. It returns back NaN values for some reason.** Why is that??

Here's my JS:

```
const input = document.querySelector('input')
let timeInterval;
let timeStop;


input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    timeStop = true;
    endTime = Date.parse(e.target.value)
    updateHTML(endTime)
})


function updateHTML(endTime) {
  let time = calculateTimeDiff(endTime)
  if (time.total <= 0) {
    timeStop = false;
  }
  for (let pro in time) {
    let el = document.querySelector(`.${pro}`)
    if (el) {
      el.innerHTML = time[pro];
    }
  }
  updateCounter();
}


function updateCounter () {
  if (timeStop) {
    timeInterval = setInterval(updateHTML, 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(timeInterval);
  }
}

//returning time remaining till date in object form 
function calculateTimeDiff(endTime) {
  let start = Date.now();
  let end = endTime;
  let t = (end-start);
  let seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  let minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  let hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  let days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    total: t,
    days: days,
    hours: hours,
    minutes: minutes,
    seconds: seconds
  }
}
```

Comment: That means you're trying to create the Date instance with a string that it cannot understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: Also calling `setInterval()` *again* from inside  the interval callback is going to cause all sorts of crazy problems.

Comment: `timeInterval=setInterval(updateHTML, 1000)` . AND `function updateHTML (endTime) {` . <--- SO undefined

Comment: `setInterval(updateHTML` calls `updateHTML` with no argument. `endTime` is undefined.

Comment: @Bob the value works initially because you call it correctly with a parameter in your event listener, but without a parameter in the `setTimeout` so it works correctly for the first time, then gets called incorrectly after one second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your code works fine but your problem is with your `endTime`. In your `setInterval`, you are calling `updateHTML` without the parameter `endTime` so that causes an error as it doesn't have a reference for the param.

You can either simply update your `updateCounter` function to accept this as a parameter and pass it to your `setInterval` function:

```
function updateCounter (endTime) {
  if (timeStop) {
    timeInterval=setInterval(() => updateHTML(endTime), 1000)
  } else {
    clearInterval(timeInterval)
  }
}
```

and then call `updateCounter` with the `endTime` at the bottom of your `updateHtml` function.

Or, remove `endTime` as a parameter from `updateHtml` and make it a global variable:

```
const input=document.querySelector('input')
let timeInterval;
let timeStop;
let endTime;


input.addEventListener('change', (e)=> {
  e.preventDefault()
  timeStop=true;
  endTime=Date.parse(e.target.value)
  updateHTML()
})


function updateHTML () {
  let time=calculateTimeDiff(endTime)
  if (time.total<=0) {
    timeStop=false
  }
  for (let pro in time) {
    let el=document.querySelector(`.${pro}`)
    if (el) {
      el.innerHTML=time[pro]
    }
  }
  updateCounter()
}


etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

When update goes from event - all is fine

But later you use `timeInterval=setInterval(updateHTML, 1000)` - and `updateHTML` **gets executed without parameter**. Use real date instead and it will work

**Working example:**

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
let timeInterval;
let timeStop;
let savedTime;

input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  timeStop = true;
  endTime = Date.parse(e.target.value)
  updateHTML(endTime)
})

function updateHTML(endTime) {
  savedTime = endTime || savedTime;
  let time = calculateTimeDiff(savedTime)
  if (time.total <= 0) {
    timeStop = false
  }
  for (let pro in time) {
    let el = document.querySelector(`.${pro}`)
    if (el) {
      el.innerHTML = time[pro]
    }
  }
  updateCounter()
}

function updateCounter() {
  if (timeStop) {
    timeInterval = setInterval(updateHTML, 1000)
  } else {
    clearInterval(timeInterval)
  }
}

//returning time remaining till date in object form 
function calculateTimeDiff(endTime) {
  let start = Date.now()
  let end = endTime
  let t = (end - start)
  let seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  let minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  let hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  let days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    total: t,
    days: days,
    hours: hours,
    minutes: minutes,
    seconds: seconds
  }
}
```

```css
.time {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <input type="date" name="endDate">
  <div class="clock">
    <div class="time"><span class="days">0</span> Days</div>
    <div class="time"><span class="hours">0</span> Hours</div>
    <div class="time"><span class="minutes">0</span> Minutes</div>
    <div class="time"><span class="seconds">0</span> Seconds</div>
  </div>


</body>

<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: You can do this, but you have to take it from somewhere. In your case you use date in parameter only first time when execute from event. But all timeout calls don't have an event and don't know where to take the date

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
const input=document.querySelector('input')
let timeInterval;
let timeStop;
let endTime;

input.addEventListener('change', (e)=> {
  e.preventDefault()
  timeStop=true;
  endTime=Date.parse(e.target.value)
  updateHTML()
})


function updateHTML () {
  let time=calculateTimeDiff()
  if (time.total<=0) {
    timeStop=false
  }
  for (let pro in time) {
    let el=document.querySelector(`.${pro}`)
    if (el) {
      el.innerHTML=time[pro]
    }
  }
  updateCounter()
}


function updateCounter () {
  if (timeStop) {
    timeInterval=setInterval(updateHTML(), 1000)
  } else {
    clearInterval(timeInterval)
  }
}

//returning time remaining till date in object form 
function calculateTimeDiff () {
  let start=Date.now()
  let end=endTime
  let t=(end-start)
  let seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  let minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  let hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  let days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    total: t,
    days: days,
    hours: hours,
    minutes: minutes,
    seconds: seconds
  }
}
```

Comment: sry, try with not sending endTime as parameter to any function as its global

Answer (score 0):

Just add preventDefault() in function updateCounter() in your code.
Hope it will work. I tried and it worked successfully.